# The trigonometric $C^*$-algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, universal-algebra

The  trigonometric  $C^*$-algebra is the universal $C^*$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{G}=\{x,y,z\}$  subject to  relations  \begin{align}x^2=x=x^*, &\quad y^2=y=y^*\\  [x, z]=y, &\quad [y,z]=-x  \\
z^*=-z,& \quad|z|\leq 1\end{align}

> Does this  universal algebra exist? Does it coincide with a well known $C^*$-algebra? What is its precise structure? How can one compute its $K$-theory?

**The motivation and reasons we call it trigonometric $C^*$-algebra:**
The classical trigonometric  coalgebra is inspired by sin and  cos. On the other hand if we put $x=\sin t, y=\cos t$, then they satisfy  $x'=y, y'=-x$. But how can we represent $d/dt$ as a relation?
Instead of  differentiation $d/dt$ we use the commutator operation with further assumption that $x,y$ are projections. I learned  this from the book by Alain Connes Non commutative Geometry page 20 (The e-version) that if $E$ is  a  curve in the space of projections of an algebra then $E'=[E,Z]$ where $Z$ is  an anti self adjoint  element, $E^*=-E$. So the  differentiation is considered as  commutator provided we work on the space of  projections. We add $|Z|\leq 1$ to guaranty  the condition of  boundedness of  generators in every arbitrary representation of generators $\mathcal{G}$

> Is the  boundedness of  $z$ a redundant condition?

Comment: Existence follows immediately from the representable functor theorem.  The same theorem also implies that the boundedness of z is necessary since otherwise the relevant functor does not preserve limits and therefore is not representable.

Comment: You can build the algebra as a quotient of the free product $\mathbb{C}^2 \ast \mathbb{C}^2 \ast C([-1,1])$, where $x$ and $y$ are $(1,0)$ interpreted in the first and second algebras and $z$ is the function $\alpha \mapsto i\alpha : [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in the third algebra. You take a quotient to impose your relations $[x,z] = y$ and $[y,z] = -x$.